# C# Dictionary LINQ

Tags: linq, list, dictionary

I have a class that returns all items in a database table (Code below).  I also have a dictionary that contains key,value pair.  Before I return the data from my function, can I look inside the dictionary and return the value that's associated with the key from my linq?

```
public IEnumerable<Code> Return_All_Codes()
        {
           return _db.Codes.ToList(); 
           //can the above list look inside my dictionary below and return Administrative when it find the number 1 for my code type?  


        }


 public Dictionary<int, string> GetCodeTypes()
        {

            var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dict.Add(1, "Administrative");
            dict.Add(2, "Regular");

            return dict; 
        }
```

Can the above list look inside my dictionary and return Administrative when it finds the number 1 for my code type? Kind of an IF statement inside my LINQ?  If 1 then Administrative, else Regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this mapping via:

```
var dict = GetCodeTypes();
return _db.Codes.AsEnumerable().Select(code => dict[code.cType]).ToList();
```

However, I'd recommend storing the dictionary in your class to prevent creating it each time, especially if this is called many times.

Comment: The table codes has about 5 fields, one of them being cType.  cType is an int and I wanted to display the value from the Dictionary instead.  Will the code above allow me to do that?

Comment: @MikeB55 The code above would return a List<string> containing the relevant strings from the dictionary (now).  If you wanted the other information, you'd just need to change the select to include it...

Comment: I'm getting an error when I use the code above.  Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,string>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @MikeB55 cType must not be an int.. check that and make sure?  Is it a `uint` perhaps?

Comment: The type is Int32 for my cType.  I also tried this code:   return _db.Codes.AsEnumerable().Select(code => dict[Convert.ToInt32(code.cType)]).ToList(); I converted the code.cType to an Int32, but I still get an error.  Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MVCProject.Data.Code>'

Comment: @MikeB55 You're using the new version (with `dict[code.cType]`)?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the code from above exactly as it's typed.  I just copied/pasted.  When I build my solution, I get this error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'

Comment: @MikeB55 You'd need to return a list or IEnumerable of string instead of Code, or make a class that contains the information from Code as well as the string.  Since your "Code" class doens't have this string, you can't return a list of it directly...